# Arduino buzzer resistor requirements

Tags: arduino, resistors, piezo-buzzer

I am currently using pin 13 and the ground pin to connect an old salvaged buzzer from an old stationary phone. Also I am using this command to power it's tone(13, 59, 30000).

Does this have the potential to damage the pins or the microcontroller itself? I aim for the loudest sound possible. Is there any other way to do this maybe through different pins (5V, Vin, etc) in order to avoid using a resistor?
Or HAVE I to use a resistor to not damage the Arduino no matter what?
Maybe I could use a transistor setup to control the buzzer? Or is the Arduino safe anyway and I should just carry on doing what I am doing (pin 13 and ground)?

Comment: depends if it is a magnetic buzzer or piezo buzzer

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 it has some weight to it. I would bet that it is magnetic. Bad news ?

Comment: Ringers in old dial phones typically use 90VAC at 20Hz. Europe is roughly similar (a bit lower voltage and 25Hz). Maybe you should post a photo of the device in question.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

It depends on model of buzzer. But the diode , resistor and transistor is needed since it probably takes 40~80mA.